Finding the minimum of a convex injective function on $\mathbb{Z}$ with fewest evaluations
We are given a convex strictly unimodal function $f$ that is only defined at integer values. I am interested in the minimum number of function evaluations needed to find the minimum.  We are guaranteed that $f$ gives a different value at each integer point.
Continuous case (background)
For continuous strictly unimodal functions the standard method is golden section search.  We  start with an interval $(a, b)$ in which the minimum must occur. Let $\phi$ be the golden ratio.

The tolerance is simply to decide when to stop and for a continuous function can be set to a small value such as $10^{-5}$.
This provably uses the smallest number of function calls possible in the worst case.
Discrete case (this problem)
However,  for my problem $f$ is only defined at integer values.  A simple adaption of the golden section search is to set $c \leftarrow b - \operatorname{round}((b-a)\cdot \frac{1}{\phi})$ and similarly $d \leftarrow a + \operatorname{round}((b-a)\cdot \frac{1}{\phi})$ where $\operatorname{round}$ rounds to the nearest integer. We now have a problem when $b - a = 2$ and so we have to have a special case where we check $f(z)$ for the single integer $a < z < b$. We also have to terminate when $b - a = 1$ and return whichever gives the smallest value.
However I don't know if this still provably uses the smallest number of function calls. I am interested in improvements as small as one function evaluation or a proof that it is already optimal.

Cross-posted: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/128240/what-is-the-optimal-number-of-function-evaluations

For a set small enough some other methods could be optimal.

The Wikipedia page about golden-section search which you referenced also provides the following description of Fibonacci search:

"A very similar algorithm can also be used to find the extremum (minimum or maximum) of a sequence of values that has a single local minimum or local maximum. In order to approximate the probe positions of golden section search while probing only integer sequence indices, the variant of the algorithm for this case typically maintains a bracketing of the solution in which the length of the bracketed interval is a Fibonacci number. For this reason, the sequence variant of golden section search is often called Fibonacci search)".

@AlexRavsky I am looking for a proof of optimality.

Your pseudo-code with two function calls per iteration is certainly not optimal, you should only make one function call per iteration.
The correct algorithm is:
We take two points $a$, $b$ with their function calls. We then call $f$ on $c=\phi^{-1}(b-a)+a$. Then, given $a < c < b$, we get the next point by calling $d = \phi^{-1}(c-a)+a$ if $c-a > \frac{b-a}{2}$, otherwise $d = b-\phi^{-1}(b-c)$, and we keep three points, depending on whichever is bigger between $f(c)$ and $f(d)$. We iterate until sufficient convergence.
For integers, an optimal algorithm is obtained by adding (as you identified), some rounding: $d = \operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}(c-a)\right)+a$.
We will first ignore the convexity of $f$, just assuming it is unimodal (because the algorithm is optimal in this more general case)
First, we can see that at each iteration, it is only necessary to keep in memory three points $a < c < b$, such that $f(c)$ is the minimum over all the calls and no calls other calls were made between $a$ and $b$. All the calls outside of $[a, b]$ do not bring more information for the minimum.
The result is independent by translation, let $M(b-a)$ be the optimal number of calls when only $a$ and $b$ are given, and $M(c-a, b-a)$ the optimal number of calls when $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given.
From now on, we will assume WLOG $a=0$ to simplify the calculations.
We have:
$$M(b) = \min\limits_c M(c, b)$$
and:
$$M(c, b)=\max\left[\min\left(\min\limits_{0 < d <c} M(d, c), \min\limits_{c < d <b}M(d-c,b-c)\right)\right]  $$
We will prove by induction that $M(c, b)$ is optimal (in particular) when $c = \operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}b)$ and $c = b-\operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}b)$.
We will show the induction WLOG for $c = \operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}b)$ since the other case is symmetric.
Let:
$$r_n = \phi^{-1}n-\operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}n)$$
Note that $-\frac{1}{2} \leq r_n < \frac{1}{2}$.
We have:
$$\begin{align}
d = \operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}c)= \operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}\operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}b)\right) &=\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}\left(\phi^{-1}b-r_b\right)\right)  \\
&=\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-2}b-\phi^{-1}r_b\right)  \\
&=\operatorname{round}\left((1-\phi^{-1})b-\phi^{-1}r_b\right)  \\
&=\operatorname{round}\left(b-\operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}b)-r_b-\phi^{-1}r_b\right)  \\
&=\operatorname{round}\left(k-\phi \,r_b\right)  
\end{align}$$
where $k$ is integer. So: $$r_c = \begin{cases}
-1-\phi \,r_b & -\frac{1}{2} \leq r_b < -\frac{\phi^{-1}}{2}\\ 
-\phi \,r_b & -\frac{\phi^{-1}}{2} \leq r_b < \frac{\phi^{-1}}{2}\\
1-\phi \,r_b & \frac{\phi^{-1}}{2} \leq r_b < \frac{1}{2}\\
\end{cases}$$
If $f(d) < f(c)$, we keep the points $a$, $d$ and $c$, and we have $d = \operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}c)$, so by induction it will be optimal for an interval of size $c$.
If $f(c) < f(d)$ ,we keep the points $d$, $c$ and $b$, so we need to show that $c=b-\operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}(b-d))$:
$$\begin{align}
b-\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}(b-d)\right)&=
b-\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}b-\phi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}c-r_c)\right)\\
& = b-\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}b-(1-\phi^{-1})c+\phi^{-1}r_c)\right)\\
& = b-\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}b-c+\phi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}b-r_b)+\phi^{-1}r_c)\right)\\
& = c+b-\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}b+(1-\phi^{-1})b - \phi^{-1}r_b+\phi^{-1}r_c)\right)\\
& = c-\operatorname{round}\left(\phi^{-1}(r_c-r_b)\right)\\
\end{align}
$$
By analysing the three cases for $r_b$, we show that $-\frac{1}{2} < \phi^{-1}(r_c-r_b)<\frac{1}{2}$, thus getting the desired result. Again, by induction, this is optimal for an interval size of $b-d$.
We will now show that $b-d = c\;(\pm 1)$ (so that the interval in both cases are almost the same size)
$$\begin{align}
b-d &= b-\phi^{-1}c+r_c\\
&=b-\phi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}b-r_b)+r_c\\
&=b-(1-\phi^{-1})b+\phi^{-1}r_b+r_c\\
&=c+r_b(1+\phi^{-1})+r_c\\
&=c\;(\pm1) \quad \text{ by considering the three cases for $r_b$}
\end{align}$$
Because $M(b)$ is monotonic, this will be optimal to split the cases in two balanced intervals since it will minimize the maximum size of these intervals, so by induction $M(b)$ is optimal for $c = \operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}b)$, the other case is symmetric.
Note that because $F_{n-1} = \operatorname{round}(\phi^{-1}F_n)$, this algorithm is equivalent to Fibonacci search when $b-a$ is a Fibonacci number.
Now, back to the case where $f$ is convex. If the input is just two calls $a$ and $b$ bounding the minimum, then this algorithm is still optimal in the worst case scenario, obtained with a convex function that with very big derivatives. However, we can try to make an algorithm that is optimal at each step of the algorithm, meaning that no matter the number of calls made, it makes a worst case optimal choice.
No matter the number of calls ($\geq 3$) made, all the information is contained in contained in $5$ consecutive (in the $<$ order) calls $a < b < c < d < e$ (with eventually $a$ and $e$ two dummy calls such that $f(a)$ and $f(e)$ are very big) where $c$ is the minimum call, $[b, d]$ is the smallest interval guaranteed to contain the minimum, $(a, b)$ gives the second highest negative slope, $(d,e)$ gives the second lowest positive slope.
If the minimum is attained between $b$ and $c$, it must be above the slopes $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, and if the minimum is attained between $c$ and $d$, it must be above the slopes $(b,c)$ and $(d,e)$. Because the minimum is guaranteed to be lower than $f(c)$, it must be attained in the interval $\left[\frac{(f(c)-f(a)(b-a)}{f(b)-f(a)}+a, \frac{(f(c)-f(d)(e-d)}{f(e)-f(d)}+d,\right]$. However, choosing the next call is very hard to optimize, since the induction depends now on $4$ points (we can assume $a=0$) but also on the value of the calls.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/128256/8998 suggests we should be using Fibonacci numbers instead. Is that compatible with what you have?

Yes, that's called the Fibonacci search, and as I indicate, it is equivalent to this algorithm when $b-a$ is a Fibonacci number. The Fibonacci search is also optimal but differs a bit when $b-a$ is not a Fibonacci number. In fact, it is probably simpler to prove the optimality of this algorithm by showing it must be better than Fibonacci search, then by proving Fibonacci search is optimal.
